# What does "trips an alley" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard in a movie description this line:

> Eddie **trips (trapes? trapeses?)** a dimly lit alley off of the red car route.

What does **trip an alley** mean? I can't find a definition of **trip** that fits this sentence. Or did I hear it wrong? I am putting [the audio clip here](https://clyp.it/abkhbkcb) (uploaded to an audio sharing site Clyp) for reference.

Comment: ****traipse**** is to walk in a leisurely or unhurried manner. "Traipse down or along a dimly lit alley"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word in the audio is "traipses". I don't think I've heard it used transitively (with a direct object) before, as it is here (I would have expected "traipses down" or "traipses along", but I don't hear any such word in this audio), but Merriam-Webster recognizes this usage: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traipse.

Comment: +1. **Traipsing** and dark alleys don't usually go together.  Traipsing suggests a nonchalance, a going hither and thither without clear purpose or plan.